# Какие формулы, функции нужно использовать, чтобы добиться результат на картинки в MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы, нажимая на переключатели на "магнитоле", менялась чистота станции и высвечивалась вместе с соответственной станцией, какие форумулы нужно использовать, функции?

Comment: Каким боком магнитола к экселю и о какого рода формулах речь?

Comment: Формулы в картинках не работают. Хотите получить помощь - прикрепляйте нормальные примеры.

Comment: магнитола -  это картинка, которая расположена на ячейках, на примере показан 99.5 и "люкс фм", это значения ячеек, с помощью ползунков должна переключатся частота и  соответствующая ей станция

Comment: В общем случае так: на картинку магнитолы цепляете кнопки, ползунки,окошки для текста и пр. активную ерунду (или создаете всю магнитолу программно). Данные из экселя запихиваете в какую-то не совсем линейную структуру (массив, список, словарь, джсон и т.д.). Вешаете обработчики действий над активными элементами, расписываете в них логику (взять данные и вставить в поле). Конкретная же реализация очень зависит от того, что это вообще будет, где будет использоваться и, какие яп и технологии используются.

Answer (score 0):

Потребуется одна функция [**ИНДЕКС() или INDEX()**](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)

Вначале облегчите задачу себе и Экселю, выбросьте из таблицы колонки, которые не нужны для решения поставленной задачи, оставьте только частоты и названия радиостанций. Получившуюся таблицу разместите на отдельном листе, например, в диапазоне $Список.A1:B27.

На другом листе (назовите его, например, Магнитола) вставьте с вкладки Разработчик элемент управления Счётчик. В его свойствах на последней вкладке заполните параметры *Минимальное значение* (1), *Максимальное значение*(26 - ведь у Вас 26 FM-станций), в *Связь с ячейкой* напишите, например, **$H$3**.

Пощёлкайте стрелками счётчика, убедитесь, что в ячейке **H3** появляются числа от 1 до 26.

Теперь в ячейки I3 и J3 впишите формулы

```
=INDEX(Список!A2:A27;Магнитола!$H$3)
=INDEX(Список!B2:B27;Магнитола!$H$3)
```

В ячейках должны отобразиться значения из таблицы радиостанций.

Теперь на вкладке Вставка выберите *Изображения он-лайн*, найдите подходящее изображение панели магнитолы и вставьте его в лист. Щелкните правой кнопкой и  переместите эту картинку на задний план. Теперь остальные элементы управления, которые Вы разместите поверх, не уползут под картинку.

Перетащите счётчик на изображение магнитолы, подправьте размер и положение.

На вкладке Вставка выберите Фигуры - Прямоугольник, нарисуйте прямоугольник поверх табло магнитолы. Пока прямоугольник выбран (видны маркеры по краю), введите в строку формул `=I3`. В прямоугольнике должны появиться цифры - частота текущей радиостанции. Воспользуйтесь кнопками форматирования, увеличьте размер шрифта, жирность, цвет, выравнивание надписи.

Повторите то же самое, но формулу напишите `=J3` - теперь на магнитоле есть название радиостанции.

Выделите все элементы управления и изображение магнитолы, выберите из контекстного меню *Группа-Группировать*. Теперь перетащите всю группу так, чтобы закрыть от пользователей ячейки с формулами `H3:J3`.

Описанный пример решения можно [**скачать с DropBox**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbs3ou7i7wopnky/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0.xlsx?dl=0)